# How to use IntentParameter in App Intent in Swift?

Tags: swift, appintents

I am working on an App Intent. It works fine in Int. I want to use the IntentParameter, say the IntentParameter.Duration. But I didn't know how to use it.

My current @parameter

```swift
@Parameter(title: "Minutes" )
var minutes:Int
```

What I want is something like below. Below is not working.

```swift
@Parameter(title: "Minutes", defaultUnit: IntentParameter<Measurement<UnitDuration>>.Duration?)
var minutes:Measurement<UnitDuration>
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the answer.

```swift
@Parameter(title: "Duration")
var duration:Measurement<UnitDuration>
```

No need to assign the `defaultUnit`.